# detect qrcode with zbar_ros

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could use zbar_ros with a webcamera to detect QRcode successfully.
But when I change the camera ,and add `<remap from="device" to="/dev/video1"/>`.

I can't start zbar_ros successfully.

The detail indormation is here.

```
 exbot@ubuntu:~/zbar_ros$ roslaunch zbar_ros example.launch 
... logging to /home/exbot/.ros/log/693c9cd0-fbab-11e4-b783-485ab6072ea3/roslaunch-ubuntu-9697.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:45860/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /barcode_reader/throttle_repeated_barcodes: 2.0
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.10
 * /uvc_camera/device: /dev/video1

NODES
  /
    barcode_reader (zbar_ros/barcode_reader_node)
    uvc_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
    zbar_manager (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [9709]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 693c9cd0-fbab-11e4-b783-485ab6072ea3
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9722]
started core service [/rosout]
process[zbar_manager-2]: started with pid [9739]
process[uvc_camera-3]: started with pid [9740]
process[barcode_reader-4]: started with pid [9775]
**[zbar_manager-2] process has died [pid 9739, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=zbar_manager __log:=/home/exbot/.ros/log/693c9cd0-fbab-11e4-b783-485ab6072ea3/zbar_manager-2.log].**
log file: /home/exbot/.ros/log/693c9cd0-fbab-11e4-b783-485ab6072ea3/zbar_manager-2*.log
[uvc_camera-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/exbot/.ros/log/693c9cd0-fbab-11e4-b783-485ab6072ea3/uvc_camera-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209322/detect-qrcode-with-zbar_ros/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peterlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/23127/peterlee/) on 2015-07-10**:
Hi, wsAndy. I wonder how can I use these codes. Do I need another QR code reader to help detect QR code? I am almost a green hand here. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Best regards, Peter

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-07-10**:
Well, you don't need another QR reader. zbar_ros is a good package. I think the reason why I couldn't use another camera to detect QR is that I use a wrong driver. As zbar_ros package just need to subscribe an image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `<remap>` tag is for ROS graph objects (topics, services, etc) rather than for ROS parameters. If you want to change the input device, you should use the `<param>` tag.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-19**:
Well, what you is really great.Thanks.
But when I changed as you said, some error occur too.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-19**:
`[manager-2] process has died [pid 4655, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=manager __log:=/home/exbot/.ros/log/b6aebed4-fe45-11e4-8e3f-485ab6072ea3/manager-2.log].log file: /home/exbot/.ros/log/b6aebed4-fe45-11e4`